How to remove "Add Profile" option from Chromium?
I'm trying to force a specific profile in my instance of Chromium for parental control reasons. Is there a way to disable additional profiles from being added? Alternatively, is there a way to enforce a certain extension that requires sign-in to apply to all created profiles?
Using Linux Mint. Thanks.
I've searched the Google Chrome Enterprise and Policy List, as well as the Stack forums, but I didn't find this option (or if I did, I'm too tech-illiterate to recognize it.)

To enforce what you want, you must use the Enterprise Policy Framework. Is that what you looked at?
